# window.scrollY dose not working in Liferay?

Tags: javascript, html, css

`window.scrollY` does not work in the page fragment.

Please tell me how  to solve this problem? `window.onscroll` is also not working. How to add click to top button in Liferay and set if `window.scrollY > 700` then show this button, else hide

`window.scrollY` value is `0` not change onscroll window in Lifeay, this code is properly working in local serv. Also `window.pageYOffset` and `document.documentElement.scrollTop` is not working in liferay

Comment: Can you explain what Liferay refers to?